# how with the help of bayes rule we can conclude this?

Tags: probability

I can't understand how the author used Bayes rule to conclude this equation:

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
P(R=1 | Q,D)& = P(D | R = 1, Q)P(R=1|Q)/P(D|Q)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

this equation taken from book *introduction to information retrieval* page 227

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is straight forward. Everything is conditioned on $Q$. Forget $Q$ for a second and apply Bayes rule.

Bayes rule says that
$$
p(R | D) = \frac{p(D|R) p(R)}{p(D)}
$$

This still holds if you have one more random variable $Q$ that you condition on. In that case
$$
p(R | D, Q) = \frac{p(D|R, Q) p(R| Q)}{p(D|Q)}
$$

Comment: thank you so much @user144410